# map a function to a Tree in haskell

Tags: haskell, tree

We can define a binary tree as such:

```
data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
            | Empty
            deriving (Show)
```

Now I've got a function, say `(+)`, how could I map it to a binary tree? How could I map an arbitrary function to a binary tree?
So `(+) a b` will be

```
Node (+) a (Node (+) Empty Empty) (Node a Empty Empty))
```

This is a homework which asks us to map a function to a tree and the above is how I understand it.
The function declaration could be:

```
 functionToTree :: (t1 -> t2) -> Tree a
```

I'm held up at defining a function type whose **number of arguments are variable**.

**EDIT**:
Sorry, as nponeccop said, I misunderstood my task and I knew how to write`functionToTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b`. Despite that I'm still curious about my original question.
To clarify a bit, here is what I've been thinking:

```
                      (+) a 
                        /  \
                      (+)   a
```

As for a function `f` taking three parameters `a` `b` `c`:

```
                     f a b 
                      /   \
                    f a    b
                    /  \
                   f    a
```

Ok, this is no longer about my homework. I just wonder whether it is possible to write such a function.
We can define a list in such way:

```
data Li a = Cons a (Li a)
          | Empty
          deriving (Show, Eq, Order)
```

Is it possible to define a **general function** like that?
If you think my question makes no sense then please down vote it.

**MORE:** I've refined my question. I think my tree is another way to illustrate partial function and curry.

Comment: People will be more likely to help you if you show an attempt at a solution, especially for a homework problem.

Comment: Thx, I've tried for hours but I don't like posting my rubbish here. You know, it's either 1 or 0

Comment: What is `(+) a b` in the context of binary tree with one value in each its node?

Comment: Do you want to treat `(+)` as a binary function? What does it mean in general to map it over a tree?

Comment: By your phrasing, I think you are not prepared yet to do this problem yourself.  An answer may give you a solution, but you will likely learn nothing.  I would suggest asking your teacher for help: an interactive conversation would probably provide a better opportunity for guidance than this forum.  There is also `irc.freenode.net` `#haskell` IRC room for interactive help.

Comment: The function signature you are looking for is probably: `functionToTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b`. So given a function from `a` to `b` you can map a `Tree a` into `Tree b`. This is analogous to map over lists, which is `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`.

Comment: I think if it's no longer about your homework then it's better to ask a new question.

Comment: why?It's still the same question and I've deleted the `homework` tag

Answer (score 1):

You didn't understand the task well. Mapping a function over a tree is applying the function to each data element contained in the tree.

I suggest you to start with drawing a tree containing numbers.

```
             1
           /   \
          2     3
           \   / \
            4 6   5
```

Can you encode this tree using your `Tree a` data type, that is, write the tree as an expression with `Node` and `Empty` constructors?

Here are some hints:

- The top node contains `1` and two non-empty subtrees.
- The left subtree contains `2`, one empty subtree and one non-empty subtree.
- The right subtree contains `3` and two non-empty subtrees.
- The level three nodes are all trees with empty subtrees.

Edit your post to insert the example tree there. Once you show us that you can do that, we can help you to proceed further.

You drew your tree wrong. The correct tree is:

```
              f 1
            /     \
         f 2       f 3
            \     /   \
           f 4  f 6   f 5
```

So you can only map functions with one argument, but not with two, three or more.

The idea is that you can (for example) add two to each element of the tree. So if you pass

```
             1
           /   \
          2     3           and (\x -> x + 2) or equivalently (+2)
           \   / \
            4 6   5
```

to your function, e.g. `tree2 = functionToTree (+2) tree1`, you get back the amended tree:

```
             3
           /   \
          4     5
           \   / \
            6 8   7
```

So each element of the tree is replaced with a new element.

Comment: Your original question is not what you were asked to do. You were asked to write `functionToTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b`, and your original question doesn't make any sense. For example, your function takes 3 parameters, but only one value is available in each node. By 'arbitrary' your teacher probably meant an arbitrary function with one argument, not with arbitrary number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Given a functional data structure (in this case, a Tree), there are usually two general things you can do with it.

1. map
2. fold

*Mapping* is where you take a function `f :: a -> b`, and a structure `origTree :: Tree a`, and apply the function to the elements of the structure, resulting in `newTree :: Tree b`. (Note that the canonical way to make a structure mappable is to make it a `Functor`, and define `fmap`)

*Folding* is where you somehow compound all elements of the structure into some new value. When you said you had a `Tree` and the `(+)` function, I immediately thought of a fold: summing all the elements in the tree. (Note that the canonical way to make a structure foldable is to make it an instance of `Foldable` (surprise!) and define `foldMap` or `foldr`)

However, it appears your homework task is to define a mapping function for your tree.

---

Now, regarding your own question, turning a function into a tree. It is a bit unclear what exactly you mean by putting `a`, `b`, and `c` into your tree, but let's play with the idea a bit. For the sake of simplicity, I'm not going to make a completely generic function. Also, since your function "trees" are rather lopsided, I'm calling them a `FunHistory` instead of a `Tree`. This will represent a history of function applications.

```
data FunHistory a b = Result b (FunHistory a b)
                    | Application (a -> FunHistory a b) a (FunHistory a b)
                    | Base (a -> FunHistory a b)
```

Now this type is a bit weird. `Result` contains a result of type `b`, as well as a link to the *previous* history of function applications. `Base` contains a function with *no* history of function applications, and the capability of *producing* a future history if a value of type `a` is supplied. `Application`, then, is an intermediate record, which provides the capability of producing a future history, as well as noting a past history, and which value was applied to that past history.

Now let's make some functions for convenience. Strap on your seat belt, this could get bumpy.

```
mkHist :: (a -> b) -> FunHistory a b
mkHist f = let h = Base (\x -> Result (f x) h) in h
```

Given a single-argument function, we can create a history out of it by...magic. This particular flavor of magic is called "laziness" and "recursive let".

Let's move on and create a function that will take a `FunHistory` and an input value, and move the history along. Sadly, this is not a total function; it is undefined for the `Result` type of a `FunHistory`.

```
-- The caller should make sure it isn't a `Result` type before using this function
app :: a -> FunHistory a b -> FunHistory a b
app x (Result _ _)        = undefined
app x (Application f _ _) = f x
app x (Base f)            = f x
```

This is fine and dandy for single-argument functions, but the intermediate `Application` constructor is never needed for such simple cases. Let's try creating a smart-constructor for a 2-argument function:

```
mkHist2 :: (a -> a -> b) -> FunHistory a b
mkHist2 f = let h = Base (\x -> mkHist' f x h)
            in h

mkHist' f x h = let h' = Application (\y -> Result (f x y) h') x h
                in h'
```

Let's try it for a 3-argument function now:

```
mkHist3 :: (a -> a -> a -> b) -> FunHistory a b
mkHist3 f = let h = Base (\x -> mkHist2' f x h)
            in h

mkHist2' f x h = let h' = Application (\y -> mkHist' (f x) y h') x h
                 in h'
```

Now a 4-argument function:

```
mkHist4 :: (a -> a -> a -> b) -> FunHistory a b
mkHist4 f = let h = Base (\x -> mkHist3' f x h)
            in h

mkHist3' f x h = let h' = Application (\y -> mkHist2' (f x) y h') x h
                 in h'
```

Well look at that; these functions look almost exactly like `mkHist3` and `mkHist2'` respectively! The next step from here would be to generalize these functions into a typeclass, so that it scales to functions with arbitrary numbers of inputs. The catch is that all the inputs must have the same type.

[warning: this code is untested, but I'm somewhat sure it's mostly correct...ish]

```
instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (FunHistory a b) where
  show (Base _) = "base"
  show (Application _ x h) = "app " ++ show x ++ ", " ++ show h
  show (Result r h) = "result: " ++ r ++ ", " ++ show h
```

Comment: would you please explain more about `mkHist` and with your code I'm not able to print anything out after having failed to `deriving (Show)`

Comment: I'm afraid the new type `FunHistory` would be infinite

Comment: Added a show instance. Still untested, but maybe that will let you play with it. I can give a little more attention to this after the holidays when I go back to my apt with my computer with haskell on it :)